# Flink add a TTL to an existing value state

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

For one of our Flink jobs, we found a state causing a state leak. To fix this we need to add a TTL to the state causing the leak, however, we would like to keep existing state(savepoint). If we add a TTL to a value state would we be able to use the existing savepoint? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, according to the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl) this won't work:

> Trying to restore state, which was previously configured without TTL, using TTL enabled descriptor or vice versa will lead to compatibility failure and `StateMigrationException`.

However, you may be able to use the [state processor API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/state_processor_api.html) to accomplish this.

However, exactly how you should handle this depends on what kind of state it is, how it was serialized, and whether the operator has a UID.